# Vagrants multiple locations and share single database?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, vagrant

I want to work on same project at multiple locations (Work and at home).

I will setup Vagrant which will have node.js and PHP installed on a virtual box. Vagrant will be setup at both locations.

When I move from location to other location, I will use github to pull the latest project.

What is the option to setup MySQL database for both location? I don't want to keep backing up latest database and then import it at different place to work on the project?

Comment: maybe set up mysql once in the cloud. [Aws Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

Comment: Why do you want to have access to the very same database? Have you considered database migrations + seeding?

Comment: @Alik What about up to date data in the database? when working in multiple locations

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back why do you need to sync database contents on a daily basis? Sure, there are some cases when you deal with a specific issue at work and want to continue research at home. In such case you can make a dump and transfer it manually. Otherwise I would recommend to use database fixtures

Answer (score 0):

Create a new DB on your live with different creds and point both vagrant projects to the new DB